# how to return expected type :int from the below code

Tags: python-3.x

In some questions and answers website, they have asked to write code as mentioned in below code

class usermaincode(object):

```
@classmethod
def lastmodified(cls, input1,input2):

  # input1:int
   #input2:int[]
   # Expected return type : int

   #please write the code here
```

Comment: I see no question here.

Comment: Please Be Precise and explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can say what you expect a function's return type to be:

```
def fun(param1: int) -> int:
    return 0
fun(3)
```

but it doesn't mean much as this will still work (IDEs like PyCharm might complain):

```
def fun(param1: int) -> int:
    return "world"
fun("hello")
```

I believe that the types given to you are just so you know what `input1` and `input2` are and to give you an idea of what to return.